# Inequalities on $L_p$ norm of Bounded Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a set of uniformly bounded measurable functions on interval $[0,1]$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Let $\tilde{\mathcal{F}} = \{e^f/\int e^f d\mu: f\in\mathcal{F}\}$ be the transformed density class. Let $\|\cdot\|_p$ be the $L_p$ norm for $1\leq p\leq\infty$. For any $f\in\mathcal{F}$, denote $\tilde{f} = e^f/\int e^f$. Show that for any $f_1$ and $f_2$ in $\mathcal{F}$,
$$\| \tilde{f}_1 - \tilde{f}_2 \|_p\leq c_1 \|f_1 -f_2 \|_p $$
and
$$\|\log(\tilde{f}_1) - \log(\tilde{f}_2) \|_p\leq c_2\|\tilde{f}_1 - \tilde{f}_2\|_p$$
for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ that only depends on $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\|f\|_\infty$.

In the paper the author says its "easy" to see these two inequalities but I've been struggling to show this explicitly for a while now. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I think the uniform boundedness and the fact that $\exp(\cdot)$ and $\ln(\cdot)$ are Lipschitz should give the results. Note that $\exp(x)$ on a bounded interval is always Lipschitz; for $\ln(x)$ to be Lipschitz, need $x$ to be on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$.

Comment: Doesn't it follow immediately from Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @WillM. which version of Jensen's inequality do you have in mind?

Comment: $\int \varphi \circ f \geq \varphi(\int f)$ for $\varphi$ convex and the underlying measure is a _probability one._

Comment: @WillM. I don't know what got hold of me today...for some reason I just can't see how does Jensen work in this case...maybe answer it below so I can at least give you some credit for your help?

Comment: Actually I don't think Jensen would work here on the difference of functions, unless there are some tricks that I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the lipschitz continuity comes to our rescue. I gave some rough estimates. Feel free to refine them.

Let us define $C:= \sup_{f\in \mathcal{F}} \Vert f \Vert_\infty$. Then we compute

$$ \Vert \tilde{f} - \tilde{g}\Vert_p 
= \frac{1}{\int e^f \int e^g} \Vert (\int e^g) e^f - (\int e^f) e^g \Vert_p
\leq \frac{1}{\int e^f \int e^g} \left[ (\int e^g ) \Vert e^f - e^g \Vert_p + \vert \int (e^f - e^g ) \vert \cdot \Vert e^g \Vert_p \right]. $$
Hence, we get
$$  \Vert \tilde{f} - \tilde{g}\Vert_p 
\leq e^{3C} \left[ \Vert e^f - e^g \Vert_p + \Vert e^f - e^g \Vert_1 \right] 
\leq 2 e^{3C} \Vert e^f - e^g \Vert_p.  $$
By the mean value theorem we get $\vert e^{f(x)} - e^{g(x)} \vert \leq e^C \vert f(x) - g(x) \vert$. Therefore, we get
$$ \Vert \tilde{f} - \tilde{g}\Vert_p \leq 2 e^{4C} \Vert f -g \Vert_p. $$

We have
$$ \frac{e^{f(x)}}{\int e^f} \geq \frac{e^{-C}}{e^C} = e^{-2C}. $$
Thus, again by the mean value theorem, we get $\vert \log(\tilde{f}(x)) - \log(\tilde{g}(x)) \vert \leq e^{2C} \vert \tilde{f}(x) - \tilde{g}(x) \vert$ and therefore we get
$$ \Vert \log(\tilde{f}) - \log(\tilde{g}) \Vert_p \leq e^{2C} \Vert \tilde{f} - \tilde{g} \Vert_p. $$

Comment: Thanks for the effort for writing it up. It took me a while and a friend's suggestion to think about this connection. In the paper I'm reading, the author simply said it is easy to see...I guess this is one of those things that once you see it, you can't unsee it.

Comment: It is kind of a standard trick (which doesn't mean it is easy if you haven't seen it before). Another instance of this trick is the fact that the Nemytskii-operator $$ C([0,1],\mathbb{R})\rightarrow C([0,1],\mathbb{R}), \ f \mapsto g\circ f $$ for $g\in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is differentiable (it's a fun exercise to do).

Comment: Just came back to this post while working on a related question. I realized that there might be a mistake in your answer? In the third line of equations, when you wrote $\|\tilde f - \tilde g\| \leq e^{3C} [\|e^f-e^g\|_p+ \|e^f-e^g\|_1] \leq 2e^{3C} \|e^f - e^g\|_p$, I'm not sure if the 1-norm is actually less than p-norm? Or if I missed something here.

Comment: @lucas_zz What I wrote is indeed correct. This is a standard fact for probability spaces that you have $\Vert f \Vert_p \leq \Vert f \Vert _q$ for any $1\leq p \leq q < \infty$. The proof is simply Hölder: $$ \Vert f \Vert_p^p = \int \vert f \vert^p = \int  1 \cdot \vert f \vert^p \leq \Vert 1 \Vert_{(q/p)^*} \Vert \vert f \vert^p \Vert_{q/p} = 1 \cdot \Vert f \Vert_q^{p}. $$ Taking the $p$-th root on both sides yields my claim. Note that for finite measure spaces we still have an inequality, but we need to put a constant in front, coming from $\Vert 1 \Vert_{(q/p)^*}$.

Comment: you are right. for some reason I was thinking about the $\ell_p$ rather than $L_p$.

Comment: This is perhaps a related question. do you have any insights on this topic? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4038578/693027