# Normalizing constants preserve metric entropy

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, entropy

Suppose $\mathcal{F}=\left\{f\in L^2([a,b]): 0<\underline{c}\leq f\leq\overline{c} \right\}$. Consider the following transformation
$$\tilde{\mathcal{F}} := \left\{\frac{f}{\int f d\mu}: f\in \mathcal{F}\right\}$$
Want to show the claim that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ have the $\epsilon$-metric entropy (log of covering/packing number under $L_2$ norm) of same order.

To put this in a more concrete context, suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ is a Sobolev ellipsoid, i.e
$$\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{E}_k(A) = \left\{f\in L^2([a,b]): f = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \theta_j\phi_j(X), \sum_{j=0}^\infty \theta_j^2j^{2k}< A\right\}$$
Suppose $k>1$ and $\phi_j$'s are uniformly bounded so that $\mathcal{E}_k(A)$ is uniformly bounded, say by a constant $\rho$. We can see that a transformation of $\mathcal{E}_k(A)$, say
$$ \tilde{\mathcal{E}}_k(A) := \left\{\frac{f + \rho + 1}{\int f d\mu + \rho + 1}: f\in \mathcal{E}_k(A) \right\}$$
is a subset of $\mathcal{E}_k(A')$ for some $A'$. In some well-published papers (eg. Yang and Barron 1999, p. 1591-), the authors claim that for $A$ large enough, $\tilde{\mathcal{E}}_k(A)$ and and $\mathcal{E}_k(A)$ have the same order of $L^2$ metric entropy. They stated in the paper "it is easy to see". While I can "see" it intuitively, I have yet to be able to come up with a rigorous proof. In Yang and Barron's paper, they also give some other function classes that they claim such property holds.

Note 1: for the Sobolev ellipsoid, I think the convex property may play a role.

Note 2: One direction is easy. Consider any $f,g \in\mathcal{F}$, and let $\tilde{f} = f/\int f$ and $\tilde{g} = g/\int g$. We can show that for some constant $C$,
$$ \|\tilde{f}-\tilde{g}\|_2 \leq C \|f - g\|_2 $$

The question is however if there's a reverse inequality of the form  $\|f - g\|_2\leq C'\|\tilde{f}-\tilde{g}\|_2 $ for some constant $C'$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true generally.
Take $\underline{c}=1$, $\overline{c}=2$, $a=1$, $b=2$.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the class of functions:
$$
\mathcal{F}_n:=\left\{x\mapsto 1+\frac{k}{n}, k\in\{0,\dots,n\}\right\}
$$
For any non-identical $f,g\in \mathcal{F}_n$, we have $||f-g||_2\geq 1/n$.
So, for $\epsilon<1/n$, the covering number is $n+1$.
However, $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}=\{x\mapsto 1\}$, which has covering number $1$.

Comment: The class I'm considering is fixed and not growing with $n$, otherwise your example would be great. But this is still an interesting example!

Comment: Also there is a formal way of showing this involving orthonormal basis, which was briefly mentioned in some early literatures such as Lucien Birge 1983 's work.

Comment: There is no need to grow $n$ here. Fix any $n$, even $n=1$ works.